# RSpec Testing Method with named arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am try testing a method call that receive a named argument, like this:

```
expect(@fake_task_search).to receive(:search).with({:query=>"a"})
        @repo.all({query:  "a"})
```

And the SUT

```
def all(params)
  @search_task.search(query: params[:query]).load
end
```

When I ran this I receive this:w rong number of arguments (0 for 1).

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: what is the full error? on which line is it?

Comment: line: @search_task.search(query: params[:query]).load

message: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).

Answer (score 6):

Call matcher the same way you call method `.with(query: "a")`

```
class Repo
  def initialize(search_task)
    @search_task = search_task
  end

  def all(params)
    @search_task.search(query: params[:query])
  end
end

it "calls" do
  @search_task = SearchTask.new
  @repo = Repo.new(@search_task)

  expect(@search_task).to receive(:search).with(query: "a")

  @repo.all({query:  "a"})
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Stub the expectation, check it out here https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class or https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-4/docs/method-stubs